# View centered on Preview but not on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am adding a fragment to an activity and it's layout is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pay_request_pbutton"
       style="@style/ButtonsStyle"
        android:text="Pay" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pay_request_rbutton"
        style="@style/ButtonsStyle"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_pay_request_pbutton"
        android:text="Request" />
    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_pay_request_bbutton"
        style="@style/ButtonsStyle"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_pay_request_rbutton"
        android:text="Bills" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And all is ok on the preview: 
[image]

But on device:

[image]

I'm using Lolipop 5.1 and overlay mode for testing layouts.

Has someone an idea why it doesn't work and what I could do to solve this kind of problem.

BTW: The fragment is very simple:

```
/**
 * Created by laurentmeyer on 15/03/15.
 */
public class PayOrRequestFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View toReturn = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pay_request, container, false);
        Button pay = (Button) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.fragment_pay_request_pbutton);
        Button request = (Button) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.fragment_pay_request_rbutton);
        configureButton(request, pay);
        return toReturn;
    }

    private void configureButton(Button request, Button pay) {
        request.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] parameters = {"com.payment.laurentmeyer.mobilepayment.fragments.ReceiveFragment", "com.payment.laurentmeyer.mobilepayment.fragments.RequestMethodsFragment"};
                mCallbacks.createSliderWithParameters(parameters);
            }
        });
        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] parameters = {"com.payment.laurentmeyer.mobilepayment.fragments.SendFragment", "com.payment.laurentmeyer.mobilepayment.fragments.VerificationFragment"};
                mCallbacks.createSliderWithParameters(parameters);

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be putting the fragment into a view container in the Activity...  You didn't post the layout for your Activity.  Does your view container have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`?

Comment: Go easy on yourself, man -- how do you think I knew what to look for?  :)

Comment: Hahahaha, this comment is great. Thanks a lot! It's typically what people call experience!